# Array with 2 variables and 1 SortDescriptor?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsarray, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to find a way to add two variables to my tableview but I don't know exactly how to do that.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"balance" ascending:NO];

//NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:2]; >>This doesn't work

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, sort2, nil]; >> Doesn't work either.

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

name and balance are on the same entity. I don't really need to sort them but I'd love to add both variables - on the same cell - to my tableview.
Any ideas ?

Comment: By adding variables to a table view do you mean you want to display the values of both the `name` and `balance` properties in a table view cell?

Comment: yes exactly! I feel like I'm missing something so simple...